# Nomenclature: Other word for non-closed polygon?

Tags: polygon

In Wikipedia, a [polygon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polygon) is defined as a  [closed polygonal chain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polygonal_chain). In other words, the term "polygon" implies that the curve is closed.

My question is: Is it common to refer to non-closed, piecewise linear curves as "polygons", too? Otherwise, is there a different term that describes general polygonal chains (other than "polygonal chain" which I find a bit long)?

Comment: Doesn't that first depend on what's actually said at which bit of Wikipedia?

Further, do piecewise linear curves generically include straight lines?

Comment: @RobbieGoodwin Yes, I'd say that a single straight line is a special case of a piecewise linear curve.

Comment: That does make sense, and does it not also imply that all straight lines are 'merely' special cases of curves?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I personally wouldn't like to describe non-closed piecewise linear curves as polygons. You might find *polyline* a better word to describe it. A *polyline* is a collection of connected straight line segments.